# tabulator: How to ignore html syntax when XLXs file is downloaded while using formatter: html

Tags: tabulator

tabulator: How to ignore html syntax when XLXs file is downloaded while using formatter: html

When i add formatter: html, i could change the style of rows.. etc. But the same when download to xlxs, i see that the html code also gets downloaded. Any option to avoid html code and display only row cell value on download.

Example.

data = [
{"id":1, "name":"Oli Bob", "age":"12", "col":"body{margin:0px} p{background-color: rgb(255,0,0); margin: 0;border: 0}

Red text

", "dob":"",},
]

downloadButtonType = {"css": "btn btn-primary", "text":"Export to Excel", "type":"xlsx"}

Answer (score 1):

Use a customFormatter like :

```
formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    return "body{margin:0px} p{background-color: rgb(255,0,0); margin: 0;border: 0}" + cell.getValue();

}
```

This way the downloader will use your raw data (Red text) but the cell will be show with your CSS formatting